# My background img is not working in react app

Tags: reactjs

my background image is not working can any buddy check it?

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./Home.css"
// backgroundimage
import bgImg from "./../assests/img/bg-sec1.jpg"

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div  styles={{ backgroundImage:`url(${bgImg})` }}>
            <h1>This is red car</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function Home() { 
  return (
    <div> 
      <div style={{ backgroundImage:url(${bgImg}) }}>
        <h1>This is a red car</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

At least you must fix typo styles->style.